# Using UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes:) in swift

Tags: ios, swift

While using UIDocumentPickerViewConroller in my code to select an audio file in app, this error came out and I can't find `(documentTypes: )at UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

[image: Error Screenshot]

```
 @IBAction func AddMusic(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeAudio as String], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        documentPicker.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UIDocumentPickerDelegate{
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]){
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported import MobileCoreServices framework?

Answer (score 17):

UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [String], in: UIDocumentPickerMode) was deprecated in iOS 14.0

That Method is replaced by this UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes contentTypes: [UTType], asCopy: Bool) method

First, You need to import UniformTypeIdentifiers

```
import UniformTypeIdentifiers
```

So, You can use this as below

```
let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.audio]
let pickerViewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(forOpeningContentTypes: supportedTypes, asCopy: true)
pickerViewController.delegate = self
pickerViewController.allowsMultipleSelection = false
pickerViewController.shouldShowFileExtensions = true
self.present(pickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I tried but I can't import UniformTypeIdentifiers. should I update Xcode?

Comment: I’m downloading 12.5 now

Comment: I've Xcode Version 12.2 and it is working